# Is there any option in Kubernetes to run pod in a specific cgroup directory?

Tags: linux, docker, kubernetes, minikube, kubernetes-pod

I am trying to limit the resource usage of each container in a pod dynamically. For docker, I used --cgroup-parent to put containers in a specific cgroup directory. However, in Kubernetes, I haven't found any option that I can do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [cgroupfs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/configure-cgroup-driver/#using-the-cgroupfs-driver) driver supported by Kubernetes.

But perhaps you just want to [set the `Pod` and `Container` resources](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/) alone? Kubernetes allows setting the limits for specific containers [as well](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#meaning-of-memory), therefore you can have app with `500Mi` RAM and logs with `50Mi` RAM (`requests`), but expand both to `1Gi` if necessary (`limits`):

```yaml
spec:
  containers:
  - name: app
    image: images.my-company.example/app:v4
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "64Mi"
        cpu: "250m"
      limits:
        memory: "128Mi"
        cpu: "500m"
  - name: log-aggregator
    image: images.my-company.example/log-aggregator:v6
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: "64Mi"
        cpu: "250m"
      limits:
        memory: "128Mi"
        cpu: "500m"
```

---

Update:

As mentioned by [David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173), you can also utilize autoscalers such as [Vertical Pod Autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler) which will adjust the Pod *resources*. For that however a [`CustomResourceDefinition`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/api-extension/custom-resources/) is necessary, therefore even the appropriate permissions to the cluster for creating CRDs and deploying it (thus may not work if you have limited access and you would need to contact the cluster admin).

> ... it will set the requests automatically based on usage ... It will also maintain ratios between limits and requests that were specified in initial containers configuration.

```yaml
apiVersion: autoscaling.k8s.io/v1
kind: VerticalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: my-app-vpa
spec:
  targetRef:
    apiVersion: "apps/v1"
    kind:       Deployment
    name:       my-app
  updatePolicy:
    updateMode: "Auto"
```

or even [Horizontal autoscaling](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/) in case you need to have separate *instances* of the applications (thus is managing the `Pod` *count*).

Comment: (...and the [vertical pod autoscaler](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler) will attempt to dynamically adjust a Deployment's resource constraints to match reality, which sounds like the goal of the original question.)

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/26751, this is the feature that I am looking for, to have Cgroup hierarchy. The team did say they implemented this. However, I have not seen any options to do so.

Comment: @ChhunSocheat For that you need to set up [QoS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/quality-service-pod/) but it'll still not allow you to specify a custom path anywhere afaik.